# how to change laravel .env file permission from 666 to 777

Tags: php, laravel, windows, permissions, development-environment

when i run Laravel project in Xamp server, during installation process through installer i got error that --Please set below directory and file permission to 777 and reload page.

Php (version 7.2 required) 8.1.5

storage/framework/
777

storage/framework/cache/
777

storage/framework/sessions/
777

storage/framework/views/
777

storage/logs/
777

bootstrap/cache/
777
public/
777
resources/lang/
777

.env (Required Permission is 777)
666

All require file permission are default to 777 but .env file is 666. how to change this permission to 777.

[image: Permissions requirement screen]

Comment: What installer are you using that it wants 777 on everything?! That's not a good idea

Comment: For Windows, you'll need to right-click on the file, and there's a tab where you can modify the permissions.

Comment: @anyber, its laravel project. During installation it writes .env file details through installer for this , it is requesting to change permission to 777 , read right and excution. Im using windows 10. giving file permission through windos is not working.

Comment: @OlD.Castor itried chmod -R etc but not working in windows 10. These thing are not recognized by windows. Thank u

Comment: @aynber , its laravel project. During installation it writes .env file details through installer for this , it is requesting to change permission to 777 , read right and excution. Im using windows 10. giving file permission through windos is not working.

Comment: It may be a Laravel project, but I haven't seen a GUI installer, which means it's something extra. What installer exactly are you using?

Comment: @Zenishabhattarai, [windows 10 set file 777](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-set-a-file-permission-to-777-in-Windows-10)